# How to break before function prologue in asm

Tags: assembly, gcc, gdb

I have the following assembly, which I'd like to see how the:

```
push %rbp
mov %rsp, %rbp
```

work before the actual code starts, for example:

```
.globl main
main:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp
    movq $8, -8(%rbp)
    mov -8(%rbp), %rax
    pop %rbp
    ret
```

However, when I run `gdb` and then `b main` and then `run`, it starts directly on the instruction `movq   $0x8,-0x8(%rbp)`. Is there a way to "start from the top" and not skip the prologue?

Comment: `starti` will start at the top of `_start`, but I think `start` is going to always stop at wherever it wants in `main`.  You can set a breakpoint at the numeric address of the top of `main`, like `b *0x123456` (copy/paste the real number) to sidestep GDB's normal skip-the-prologue "feature".  Or apparently `b *main` works, per this answer: [How does GDB determine the address to break at when you do "break function-name"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31451340)

Comment: Don't forget to search for duplicate questions before posting; especially for this one it seems easy to find.  For me, a google search on `site:stackoverflow.com gdb break before prologue` found several hits including [Why is GDB breakpoint set at the wrong address for an x86 assembly function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46878778) and the duplicates I used to close this.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks, the answer with doing `*main` works great. What do you mean by "copy/paste the memory address" -- how/where would I find that address?

Comment: Before searching and finding you could use `*main` instead of a numeric address, I meant finding the address from disassembly in GDB; it shows you the addresses.  Or `p main` should also show you the address.  Then copy/paste that or type it on a `b *number` command.  But since `b *main` works, you don't need to do that.  However, that is a way to set a breakpoint on any instruction you want without having to figure out a line number for it or anything like that.